# Rails Etag generation process not considering changes of layout file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, etag, http-caching

I am learning HTTP caching in Ruby on Rails version 5.  Below is my code for HTTP caching in the controller.

```
if stale?(@user)
  respond_to do |format|
   form.html
  end
end
```

while this code works perfectly and gives the 200 response back whenver there is a change in template of the action, but the problem is with layout file and javascript and css assets.

I have edit these(layout,css,javascript) files but the server still returns 304 response instead of 200 as a result i see old data on the webpage.

Do i need to mention somewhere in the code to use layout,css and javascript containt for etag generation. if so then etag generation process will be very heavy and page loading will be done very slowly.

Please advice

Thanks

Comment: Which mode are you facing this problem in? Dev? Production? That information is useful here.

Comment: @vee - i am facing this problem in development mode but it would be nice if you suggest solution for both ENV.